How to flash an Arduino Due (ARM Cortex-M) using openocd?
I'm wondering if I can flash an Arduino Due, that has an AT91SAM3X8E chip using openocd without something like an FTDI adapter. I tried reading the openocd docs and Arduino Due docs, but I'm still quite confused.
For example, Arduino Due wiki (programming port section) mentions the following

The Arduino Due has two USB ports available. The Native USB port
(which supports CDC serial communication using the SerialUSB object)
is connected directly to the SAM3X MCU. The other USB port is the
Programming port. It is connected to an ATMEL 16U2 which acts as a
USB-to-Serial converter. This Programming port is the default for
uploading sketches and communicating with the Arduino.

This sounds to me like I should be able to do the same manually (without using the Arduino IDE) to flash the chip, but I'm not sure how to configure openocd for this.
I'm going through different interface configurations in arduino/openocd fork, but can't quite get it working (and struggling to understand what's going on).
I've compiled the program using the following commands:
$ arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -o a.elf main.c
$ arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O ihex -j .text -j .data a.elf a.hex

Now, is there anyway I can upload this program to the MCU using openocd and the USB programming port exposed by the Arduino Due?

As far as I can tell: nope, Arduino for some reason gave its users a more complicated, less useful interface for programming than possible.
You'd want, as you tagging indicates, a jtag debugging port – or, since this is an ARM microcontroller – probably a swd debugging port to talk to. OpenOCD doesn't "talk" Arduino bootloader protocol, and even if it did, it'd be less useful than the actual SWD interface on the ATSAM itself.
Instead, you get a serial port that only talks to the Arduino bootloader, which allows you to load new software using the arduino-specific protocol. But it doesn't do any of the debugging that the native debugging interface offers. Arduino's hardware and software design is in the way of good microcontroller firmware development here.
So, solution is easy, probably: don't use either of the USB ports that the arduino Due offers. They are useless for your purpose of flashing software quickly and debugging it while it runs (it is hard to overstate how much better that is than having to get data out via LED blinking of serial port writing). Instead, buy one of the many ST-Link v2 clones that there are – maybe don't go for the very cheapest one, but you really don't need to spend more than 10€ on the hardware – and connect it directly to the SWDIO and SWCLK and NRST and VDD&GND pins on your cortex. (don't connect external power, else the power from the ST-Link v2 and that power will compete). Use your own cables, the ones shipped with these devices are usually very unreliable.

ST-Link v2 clone. Source: amazon.com, search for "st-link v2"; original source uncertain, sellers seem to steal photos among each other
I found the cheapest way to get such a programmer in a reliable form is by buying a (new with free shipping or used) ST Nucleo-64 dev board and simply using the one integrated there; I've marked the SWD pins in pink and the jumpers you need to change to disconnect the debugger from the "main" chip on that board below:

Source: st.com, changing URLs, look for "ST Nucleo-64". Of course, you might end up with a board that's superior to your Arduino Due in every way. Happens.
The ST-Link V2 is perfectly supported in openOCD. This article has a picture of how to connect things:

Source: Ivankravets, platform.io Community, CC-by-SA 3.0

Not OpenOCD exactly, but yes you can use SAM-BA or Bossa and make use of the bootloader that the SAM3X8E has in silicon. I think you just have to hold down the reset and clear buttons. You don't need any external tool other than a USB micro cable. Connect to the native USB port.
